# Availible parameters at ODBC connection string in PHP

Tags: php, odbc, connection-string, sap-ase

I'm using `odbc_connect()` to connect to Sybase ASE server. Now I'm using the string like this:

```
odbc_connect("DSN=DsnName;
              charset=utf8;
              clientcharset=utf8;
              KeepOrgMultibyte=1;
              app=$appname", 
              $user, 
              $password);
```

But now I faced a need to specify some more options and I tried to find what can I add. [Here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/adaptive-server-enterprise-odbc-driver/) we can see some options available but they aren't actually exhaustive because option like `clientcharset` works fine. Also I need to add `MinPoolSize` and `MaxPoolSize` as mentioned [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sybase-adaptive/), but I don't know will it work or not. So where I can find all available option that I can specify in connection string?